# how to merge toes on foot to create socks?

Tags: modeling

I am an newbie to blender.

I wish to create socks from the foot. I wish to merge toes to make it seems like a sock.is any convenient way to do that in blender?
[image]

Comment: I suppose I would try a shrink-wrap first and just see what the results are like

Comment: If you do get get a decent result with shrink-wrap, you might try duplicating the foot, separate and remove the toes. Extrude foot region  and retry shrink-wrap

Comment: You can also select all your toes' vertices and try `Mesh > Convex Hull` in edit mode to get a sock like shape around the toes. With that you can go on and for example shrinkwrap the real geometry.